# Recommended profiling method for Java EE deployed in JBoss AS 5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, profiling

I'm attempting to profile a Java EE project (EJBs, Servlet, JSP) which is deployed in JBoss Application Server 5.

I would like to find the methods which use the most cpu and memory.

What are the recommended methods and tutorials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) in Eclipse. This gives you a button to start the server in profile mode (and to deploy your app to the server).

Another option is to add `-agentlib:JPIBootLoader=JPIAgent:server=standalone;CGProf` to the startup script of JBoss and attach a standard profiling tool (like TPTP) to the running instance, see [Profiling J2SE 5.0 based applications using Eclipse TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/platform/documents/tutorials/jvmti/Java_Application_Profiling_using_TPTP-v2.0.html).

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to start the server in profile mode, as you told: _'Could not launch in profiling mode because no profilers are configured.'_ I have JBoss Tools installed. What am I missing?

Comment: @theV0ID: TPTP is no longer maintained, you will need to install another profiler if you are on newer eclipse versions.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling Do you have some alternative to TPTP ?